# How can read I read a text file with that has css declarations with nodejs and count how many times a value accurs in the file?

Tags: css, node.js, string

Here is a sample of whats in the file:

```
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 16px;
letter-spacing: 0.09em;
text-align: left;

font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 21px;
letter-spacing: 0em;
text-align: center;

font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 16px;
letter-spacing: 0.09em;
text-align: left;
```

So font-family: Roboto; would be 3 times,
font-size: 14px; 2 times,
font-size: 18px; 1 times
etc..

The css is not mine, its from figma. I just copied and pasted them in a text file.

Comment: aren't you missing some selectors and `{}`?

Comment: What if someone used the shorthand `font` instead of the specific `font-family`? This task is an *XY-Problem* I believe. Where is the JS code you tried? Do you know how to read a file? What was your further research and how do you think you should approach this problem?

Comment: If you research, "how to read a file in NodeJS" there's your file. Then research "get file lines", then research "split string at certain character" or "how to use regex to get property and value of CSS alike string"... that would be a starting point to show an attempt in resolving your own issue. Read: [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Also, you did not explained if you want to map all the properties values counts or you just want to return a single integer from your function given a specific value?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the css is not mine, its from figma. I copied and pasted them into a text file. I know how to read a file, but Im new to coding. Its just difficult for me.

Comment: Figma? doesn't Figma also creates selectors? i.e: `.foo { ` etc? And what's the purpose in counting how many times a value is present in a CSS-alike string?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I want to map all the value counts.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i dont know ,much about figma, i just started using yesterday. i just went to the typography section on the right panel and if you click it, it will copy.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you building? Why would you need to count how many time a value was used? I see no purpose. Take for example `margin: 10px; padding: 10px;` Why would you want to get `2`? Or you meant to count specific Property AND Value together? Please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 1):

You can manage to do that using the **fs** package that is inclueded in node.

With the **fs** package you can read the file.

And then using a regular expression get all the ocurrences of your css.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function countValueOccurrences(filename, property, value) {
  // Read the contents of the file into a string
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8');

  // Define a regular expression to match CSS declarations
  const declarationRegex = new RegExp(`${property}\\s*:\\s*${value}\\b`, 'gi');

  // Use the regular expression to match all occurrences of the value
  const matches = fileContents.match(declarationRegex);

  // Return the count of occurrences of the specified value
  return matches ? matches.length : 0;
}

// Example usage
const filename = 'styles.css';
const property = 'font-size';
const value = '20px';
const count = countValueOccurrences(filename, property, value);
console.log(`The value ${value} occurs ${count} times in the file ${filename}.`);
```

Comment: This is not exactly what OP asked for: *"count how many times a value occurs in the file"* there was no mention about matching CSS properties

Comment: Also, a wise suggestion would to to *always* use a regExp escaper in combination with `new RagExp` variables strings.